# Nothing appears when run the page after building by Webpack compiled?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am facing this problem :

First, I am starting webpack to build the project. On localhost, everything works fine. In the build folder, index.html and index.js are getting built.

But, when I run it in the browser (not using local server) but using these files, it appears "not found". 
Checked webpack.config.js - everything is placed in a single index.js.
This is webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'build/index.js',
    publicPath: '/build'
  },  
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "app"),
        query: {
          presets:['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

There is no eror. But there is text "Not found"

Comment: configure `publicPath`.

Comment: I added publicPath, but it doesn't work too
 ` 
output: {
  filename: 'build/index.js',
    publicPath: '/build'
  }
`

Comment: Provide your `webpack.config.js` and the error message.You can edit you question.

Comment: I try to use reactIonic and when I run webpack-dev-server it working correctly, but when I run builded index.html it can't display normal page

Comment: It can't find `index.html` or `build/index.js`?

Comment: index.html was created by me. In index.html i created simple markup, that has div, who has id "root". So index.js make all things in id "root". index.html:
`
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
 <meta name="description" content="Use Ionic with React" />
 <title>Reactionic React Ionic</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
`

Comment: and about index.js. it is in "filename: 'build/index.js',"

Comment: Try to change script's src to build/index.js

Comment: index.js connects to index.html. Resolve is no that.
if i write <script src="build/index.js"></script> - i get error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" because 2 files are in folder "build".

Comment: Sorry,I don't know how to solve this.